# Synology client connecting to OpenVPN server?

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn, nas

I have setup an OpenVPN server on a Cloud VM using easy-rsa. To create my new client I ran this command:

```
./easyrsa sign-req client client
```

Then I used the default example to get the ovpn configuration:

```
cp /usr/share/doc/openvpn/examples/sample-config-files/client.conf client.ovpn
```

So I have:

- `client.crt`
- `client.key`
- `ca.crt`
- `client.ovpn`

Then I logged to my NAS, went to Control Panel/Network/Network Interface/Create/VPN. I choose OpenVPN and filled the form:

[image]

Unfortunately, this configuration expects a User/Password, but I don't have any, since I have the certificates.

What should I do? What did I miss?

Answer (score 0):

If your `.ovpn` file contains embedded certificates (at the end of the file you have:

```
...

# Set log file verbosity.
verb 3

# Silence repeating messages
;mute 20

key-direction 1
<ca>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</ca>
<cert>
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</cert>
<key>
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
...
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
</key>
<tls-crypt>
#
# 2048 bit OpenVPN static key
#
...
</tls-crypt>
```

Then you don't need to add any other file.

For the Username and Password. Enter any values for example `Username`, `Password`. It will be accepted and the connection should work.